# List of GIS Challenges, Competitions or Puzzles

Tags: references

In software development there are tons of various challenges or competitions, just take a look at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/challenge).

Also, there are challenges with huge prizes involved, such as for [netflix competition](http://www.netflixprize.com/) (data mining task for movie recommendations).

Even more, in software development learning is usually by solving puzzles, varying from such simple tasks as reordering of a stack or reinventing dijkstra algorithm to more complicated, such as AI for checkers.

These puzzles/competitions are not only great for competing, but they also 'force' you to search, study and improve your skills.

After having a quickie with google, I couldn't find much. There was a [poster competition](http://www.urisa.org/gisday_posters), we can also say that TSP or VRP is somewhat of GIS challenges. It seems that ESRI also held some kind of [competition](http://www.esriaustralia.com.au/esri/2152.html).

So my question is as following -- are there any competitions or (even more importantly) puzzles (for learning mostly) for GIS?

Answer (score 7):

[gis.stackexchange.com](http://gis.stackexchange.com) has encouraged me to 'search/study & improve' my GIS skills.

In the last year I have learnt a whole lot from watching the tags im interested in on GIS.se.

I do not consider questions on gis.se as a competition or a challenge, and only try to answer Qs that I think I have something to offer on.
- However, when I do answer a Q and I get credit for my answers, the reputation+ is def encouraging.

I like the idea of having a challenge tag for gis.se, but might be worth discussing what that would entail on [meta.gis.stackexchange.com](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I agree that this should be on meta. Both asking and answering questions on here (and other stack exchange sites), is a wonderful way to expand my knowledge.

Comment: Yes this site is great for learning and almost any question could be considered as a challenge or puzzle. But I want something that would be more in a form of "given this data do this" -- a TSP would be great example of what I mean 
http://www.tsp.gatech.edu/data/ml/monalisa.html

Comment: @Andy This *reply* belongs on meta (due to its focus on GIS.SE and because it's difficult to construe it as a response to the question), but the question appears to be on topic for the main site, which welcomes a wide range of inquiries about anything related to GIS.

Answer (score 2):

For GIS? or software dev?  I found this for GIS:

Event Details:

The GeoTech Center is now accepting applications for the 2011-2012 National Geospatial Technology Skills Competition.  The competition consists of three rounds:

1. Round 1: Online Objective Exam (based on the Dept. of Labor Geospatial Technology Competency Model GTCM)
2. Round 2: GIS Project video (5 minute YouTube video of student’s project)
3. Round 3: Professional presentation @ the 2012 Esri International User’s Conference in San Diego, July 2012! (top 6 finalists receive a $2000 stipend to attend)

Students must qualify and register at: http://www.geotechcenter.org/.  The Competition tab has the complete rules/description and registration form.  Example videos from last year’s competitors are also posted on this link.  Now is a great time to incorporate the Round 1 exam into your GIS course for Fall 2011 and Round 2 will be ideal for your Spring 2012 GIS course project.

Comment: Looks interesting, I wonder if Online Objective Exam will be posted freely for everyone